# pass value from view to controller in codeigniter using onclick

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to send the id of a button onclick frome view to controller through ajax but it return the error:

> 500 Internal Server Error

**my view:**

```
<a data-toggle="modal"data-target="#Add_Money_to_campaign" ><button onclick="addId('<?php echo $id;?>');"> Add</button></a>
```

**controller**

```
       $id= $this->input->post('dataString');
        $this->model->function($id);
```

**script:**

```
function addId(id){
       var dataString = id
       alert(dataString)
   $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('controller/function');?>",
    data: {dataString:dataString},
    cache: false,

    success: function(html){



        alert(html); 


        }
    });

}
```

Comment: give your full path in ajax call <?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/controller/function

Comment: no that is not working i have done that before i post the question..

Comment: have your code reaches to controller function

Comment: Try to `print_r` or `echo` within your controller function are you getting `id` over there or show your controller function code

Comment: Are you getting `id` value within your controller

Comment: no i am not geting the value in controller..

Comment: try to alert your `'<?php echo base_url('controller/function');?>'` are you getting full path to your function @pawan

Comment: yes i am getting the full path and echoing id i got an error **Message: Undefined index: dataString**

Comment: Can you please post your question with controllers code so it might be easy to understand what wrong with code. @pawan

Comment: i have edited my controller code..

Comment: @pawan I have updated my answer check if it works

Answer (score 1):

I'm updating your code

**Your view:**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Add_Money_to_campaign" ><input type="submit" value="Add" onclick="addId(<?php echo $id;?>);" /></a>
```

**Your JS:**

```
function addId(id){
   var id = id
   alert(id);
   $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('controller/function');?>",
    data: {id:id},
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function(result){
            console.log(result); 
        }
    });

}
```

**Your function**

```
 $id= $this->input->post('id');
 echo $id; 
 $this->model->function($id);// you might have error over here you need to specify your model_name as my_model
```

Comment: Whats the error `500 internal error` then check your parameters name instead. From where you are getting value of `$id` is it an array or you are passing it within `foreach loop` and are you getting `id` value within ajax @pawan

Comment: i am getting the value on alert, i want to use this value in my where clause to update my database, so i need it as an int value.

Comment: So it means atleast we are correct within halfway now try to echo value within controller and check are you getting value over there or not and within PHP you can check with `is_numeric` function as **if(is_numeric($id)){// your code}**